# Java generics: put() on Map<String,capture#3-of ? extends AbstractClass> is not applicable for the arguments (String, AbstractClass)

Tags: java, generics, capture

I'm trying to implement a sort of intern factory for multiple classes that extend from a common parent. Much of the logic is identical, but it can't really be inherited because the lookups need to be static. The desired syntax is something like:

```
Car c = AbstractClass.valueOf(Car.class, "Ford");
```

with Car having specific methods related to cars, but the instances are stored in a common cache. Here's what I have so far. My compile error is on the put in the constructor:

"The method put(String, capture#3-of ? extends AbstractClass) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (String, AbstractClass)"

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public abstract class AbstractClass {

    private static Map<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, LinkedHashMap<String, ? extends AbstractClass>> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, LinkedHashMap<String, ? extends AbstractClass>>();

    private static synchronized <T extends AbstractClass> Map<String, T> getNameMap(Class<T> clazz) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, T> nameToEnum = (LinkedHashMap<String, T>) map.get(clazz);
        if (nameToEnum == null) {
            nameToEnum = new LinkedHashMap<String, T>();
            map.put(clazz, nameToEnum);
        }

        return nameToEnum;
    }

    public static <T extends AbstractClass> T valueOf(Class<T> clazz, String name) {
        return getNameMap(clazz).get(name);
    }

    public static <T extends AbstractClass> Collection<T> VALUES(Class<T> clazz) {
        return getNameMap(clazz).values();
    }

    public static <T extends AbstractClass> Set<T> SORTED_VALUES(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new TreeSet<T>(getNameMap(clazz).values());
    }

    AbstractClass(String name) {
        AbstractClass.getNameMap(this.getClass()).put(name, this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the javadoc for `Object.getClass()`, the returned type is a wildcard based compile-time type of the expression.  Since the compiler only knows that `this` returns an AbstractClass instance, `this.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends AbstractClass>`.

This means your call to `getNameMap` in the constructor will return a `Map<String, ? extends AbstractClass>`.  Which means that, while the returned Map has values of a specific (non-wildcard) type, that exact type isn't known at compile-time;  the compiler only knows the Map's values are required to be either AbstractClass or something that inherits from AbstractClass.  So the compiler can't safely add `this` as a value, since it isn't known at compile-time which subtype of AbstractClass `this` represents.

To use a simpler example:  if a method returned `Map<String, ? extends Number>` then the compiler wouldn't know whether it was safe to add an Integer to the Map, because the Map's actual, non-wildcard type might be `Map<String, Double>`, `Map<String, Short>`, etc.

As for a solution: I don't think there is a way to have a Map use generics to match each individual key's type with its corresponding value's type.  I would forget about using bounded types on the inner Maps' values, and use dynamic casting instead:

```
private static Map<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, Map<String, AbstractClass>> map = new HashMap<>();

private static synchronized Map<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, Map<String, AbstractClass>> getNameMap(Class<T> clazz) {
    // same as before
}

public static <T extends AbstractClass> T valueOf(Class<T> clazz, String name) {
    return clazz.cast(getNameMap(clazz).get(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store anything that is an AbstractClass, just declare your map as

```
private static Map<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, LinkedHashMap<String, AbstractClass>> map = 
    new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, LinkedHashMap<String, AbstractClass>>();
```

This would allow you to store any instance of AbstractClass or its subclasses in the inner map, against AbstractClass or one of its sub class.

Comment: If I do that, then the return type of getNameMap() is no longer <String, ? extends AbstractClass> and the valueOf() method cannot return the actual type. It can only return type AbstractClass which has to be cast to the appropriate type. It should be able to made to work so you can do: Car car = AbstractClass.valueOf(Car.class, "Ford").

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can basically be boiled down to this:

Given a method with this signature:

```
public static <T> void foo(T x, Class<T> y);
```

and a variable of any reference type:

```
<any reference type> bar;
```

it is impossible to pass `bar` and `bar.getClass()` to this method:

```
foo(bar, bar.getClass()); // error
```

even though it is provable that there always exists some `T` for which it is correct (i.e. `T` = the actual runtime type of `bar`).

It is due to the special case in the language for the type of `.getClass()` that causes this problem.

I can think of two ways to solve this:

1) Cast the class object to be parameterized by the same type as the reference (even though this is technically not true):

```
AbstractClass(String name) {
    AbstractClass.getNameMap((Class<AbstractClass>)this.getClass()).put(name, this);
}
```

2) Cast the object to the same type as the parameter of the class method. This will require a capture helper due to the wildcard in the class's type:

```
private static <T> void helper(Class<T> clazz, String name, Object obj) {
    AbstractClass.getNameMap(clazz).put(name, (T)obj);
}
AbstractClass(String name) {
    helper(this.getClass(), name, this);
}
```

(if you don't want that unchecked cast you can do `AbstractClass.getNameMap(clazz).put(name, clazz.cast(obj));`)